# UIPickerview to select employees and IDs

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, uipickerview

I have a dictionary with all employee IDs and their names in it. Now I want the user to select a name using the UIPickerView. Problem is: if I sort the values (the names) of the dictionary, how do I know which name corresponds to its ID as there could be identical names in the dictionary.

e.g.

```
{"0001", "John Doe"}
{"0002", "John Doe"}
{"0003", "Jane Doe"}
{"0004", "Jane Alpha"}
{"0005", "Jane Doe"}
```

So if I sort the resulting array with all the values and show this in the UIPickerView and select the third row (Jane Doe), how can I then get its corresponding ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating two separate arrays for Name and IDs I created (as suggested by iDev) a custom object 'Person' with these 2 properties. I created a new Person object and added each one to an array.

Then I sorted that array using

> sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)

Then in titleForRow I return the Name of the person:

> ((Person *)[mySortedArray objectAtIndex:row]).Name;

Answer (score 1):

1- In case you want to sort the values of dictionary you construct your dictionary values with with unique names as if you do for key.

2- If your are not be able to do that in case you have your simple dictionary let the user select *John Doe* out of 3.

3- If there are value duplication when showing in the picker you avoid repeating name and show it once.

Comment: but how do I map the selected value to its ID if the Names are identical?

Comment: since it's just a string (not a employee record) just take the name alone form the picker

Comment: I dont understand that. If I want to show (e.g. in alertView) the ID of Jane Doe (the second one) which in the UIPickerView would be the third row then how do I do that?

Comment: It s a wrong approach because u should not use value to find key

Comment: then how should I do that? I want the user to select the values in ascending order and not the key.

Comment: Instead of keeping values as string keep it as model object. So that it would be unique

Comment: you got a little neat example for me? :) Thx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60101/discussion-between-danielr-and-idev).

Answer (score 0):

You can get selected dictionary as bellow

```
NSDictionary *aDict = [yourArrayName objectAtIndex:[self.yourPickerName selectedRowInComponent:0]];
NSLog(@"%@", aDict);
```

Comment: The Array with the Names is ordered (to show Names in ascending order in the UIPicker). So how do I get the ID from the selected row if there are multiple identical Names in the Array?